# what is the file type like *.lh and *.lc on the book UNPv13?

Tags: c, unix, network-programming

Recently, I am struggling in reading the book [**UNPv13**](http://unpbook.com/src.html). I have downloaded the [**source code**](http://unpbook.com/unpv13e.tar.gz). And there are some strange files like **.lh* and **.lc* under the directory **unpv13e/lib/**. Correspondingly, there are also **.h* and **.c* file contained similar contents. I am just very curious, so search it at google and SO for a long time, but didn't get any useful information.

Comment: I am sorry, the man who have given me -1 , can you let me awake ?

Comment: Yeah, i know. But there is no helpful answer for this question until now.

Answer (score 0):

To take one pair of files, almost at random (largely arbitrary selection):

#### sockopt/checkopts.c

```
/* include checkopts1 */
/* *INDENT-OFF* */
#include    "unp.h"
#include    <netinet/tcp.h>     /* for TCP_xxx defines */

union val {
  int               i_val;
  long              l_val;
  struct linger     linger_val;
  struct timeval    timeval_val;
```

#### sockopt/checkopts.lc

```
/* include checkopts1 */
#include    "unp.h"##  1 ##src/sockopt/checkopts.c##
#include    <netinet/tcp.h>     /* for TCP_xxx defines */##  2 ##src/sockopt/checkopts.c##

union val {##  3 ##src/sockopt/checkopts.c##
  int               i_val;##  4 ##src/sockopt/checkopts.c##
  long              l_val;##  5 ##src/sockopt/checkopts.c##
  char              c_val[10];##  6 ##src/sockopt/checkopts.c##
  struct linger     linger_val;##  7 ##src/sockopt/checkopts.c##
  struct timeval    timeval_val;##  8 ##src/sockopt/checkopts.c##
```

The version with the `.lx` suffix has line numbers added as pseudo-comments.  They're not compilable source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And so the version with the .lx suffix has no any use. But why the author provided these corresponding files ? I am just very curious.

Comment: I don't know why they're provided; I've not reread the book to check what it says about what's in the downloadable software.  I just went to where I have my download of the upnv13e source and found the files there.  It will likely be something to do with the annotating the code for the book, but I'm not sure why it is distributed.